# 'Unexpected token' React component

Tags: reactjs

Could anyone tell me what error I'm making when writing this component. I'm being told unexpected token and I can't see the mistake.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <h1>React FireBase</h1>
            )
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting `Unexpected token <` ?

Comment: Yeah, but I cant see the mistake.

Comment: Did you load in the React library before you put in that code?

Comment: Sorted it, just ran 'npm start' again and it started working.